# Androidplot align title of the plot at the right corner

Tags: android, androidplot

Which property is using to set the title of the plot at the right corner. Right now the title is showing in the middle.

[image]

I need the Lead II is displayed at the right corner of the plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
plot.getTitleWidget().position(0, XLayoutStyle.ABSOLUTE_FROM_RIGHT, 0,
    YLayoutStyle.ABSOLUTE_FROM_TOP, AnchorPosition.RIGHT_TOP);
```

In future release (most likely 1.0) you'll also be able to do this via XML attrs.